# Absurd Equation

Tags: mathematics

$37$ $12$ $9$ $×$ $2.5$ $÷$ $+$ $=$ $X$

Solve for $X$

Hint 1

> Uhyhuvh Srolvk Qrwdwlrq

Hint 2

> Hint 1 needs to be decoded

Comment: 2 straight hints? :-/ You should hold on before posting hints.

Comment: I thought the spoilers would be enough, so that everyone can decide for themselves if they want to use the hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the face of it, this looks like postfix notation, if that's so, then

> it can be rewritten as ((12*9)/2.5)+32=X, or X = 80.2

Additionally, the hint decodes to

> Reverse Polish Notation, in Rot23, which is another name for Postfix Notation.

Answer (score 4):

X =

> 80.2

The equation is

> in [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)